Windows PowerShell Get Registry '(Default)' 'Value Size' and 'Value data'
If I use regedit, I can view Registry 'Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents'.
The only entry is:
Name (Default)
Type 'REG_SZ'
Data (Value not set)'
If I double-click on the '(Default)' entry:
Value name: (Default)
Value data: <blank>
I've tried numerous ways to access the 'Type' and 'Data' contents without success.
I've tried using:
(1) $key = Get-Item -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents' 

(2) foreach ($name in $key.GetValueNames())  

but this either results in an exception or doesn't get the values.
I've found nothing on the web that has a simple explanation of how to access the '(Default)' type and data values.
Anyone who can provide a simple way to do this?
I've tried many ways to get the name and data values.

If regedit displays (Default) REG_SZ (value not set), this means that such a value with a blank name does not technically exist for this key. Therefore, any registry tool will fail to retrieve this value. Perhaps it is a little misleading that regedit displays this placeholder, but this is just a display convention of regedit and not an indication that an empty value with a blank name really exists. Only if the default entry of a key is really set with a value (and a type), the registry tools can retrieve this value.

Your comment clarified how regedit interprets keys that don't technically exist.



Assuming that a given registry key exists, it may or may not have an unnamed value, which regedit.exe represents as (Default) in its GUI.

Similarly, the GUI showing a Data value of (Value not set) implies that this value doesn't exist, so there's nothing to retrieve.

If the unnamed value does exist, you can retrieve its value:

Using the Get-ItemPropertyValue PowerShell cmdlet:

Refer to it by literal string '(Default)' (irrespective of what the Windows display language is) as the -Name argument.
# NOTE: FAILS, if the unnamed value doesn't exist.
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents' -Name '(Default)'


As an aside: Due to a bug, still present as of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4.x, Remove-ItemProperty does not recognize '(Default)' - see GitHub issue #6243.



Alternatively, using the .NET .GetValue() method of the [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey] type, in combination with Get-Item, which outputs such instances (when targeting the registry).:

Use '', i.e. the empty string:
# NOTE: Returns $null, if the unnamed value doesn't exist.
(Get-Item -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents').GetValue('')


If the unnamed value exists, it is also returned as a '' element from the .GetValueNames() method.







If you want to quietly default to $null if the unnamed value doesn't exist:
# Using Get-ItemPropertyValue.
# NOTE: Also ignores the nonexistence of the *key*.
$unnamedValueDataIfAny =
  try { Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents' '(Default)' -ErrorAction Stop } 
  catch { $null }

# Using .NET.
# NOTE: Reports an *error* in the event of nonexistence of the *key*.
$unnamedValueDataIfAny =
  (Get-Item -Path 'HKCU:\AppEvents').GetValue('')


Your answer, in combination with the comment from Halfix provided the basis of what I was looking for.
I've been attempting to use the Get-ItemPropertyValue with try..catch to provide output similar to the following:
Start Path:  'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents'
Subkey Name: 'PLACEHOLDER'
Subkey Type: 'DOES NOT EXIST'
Subkey Size: 'DOES NOT EXIST'
Subkey Data: ''
This output will be used in a larger script that I've been working on to search the Registry.
When I get this working bug free it may be useful to others, but for now I wanted to provide some feedback to the community.
